# R - Multiple artists Spotify API function

Tags: r, list, spotify

Apologies for the newbie question but I'm struggling with the following;

I'm using the tiagomendesdantas/Rspotify function to access the Spotify API via R. When using this to access information on single artists, playlists or tracks it works fine but I want to run this for multiple artists at once.

I tried creating lists etc. but that doesn't work.

```
#Getting the songs of Spotify's RapCaviar playlists
rapcaviar <- getPlaylistSongs(ownerid = "Spotify",
                              "37i9dQZF1DX0XUsuxWHRQd",
                              token = keys) 
rapcaviar
```

What should I do to include multiple ID's for either playlists or artists?

I often get the error:

`Error: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE`

Ideally you'd use the outcome of the `getartistinfo` function for other options like `getfeatures` to retrieve the acoustic elements of songs.

Help is much appreciated (and hopefully/probably rather easy? ;-))

Link to function: https://github.com/tiagomendesdantas/Rspotify/blob/master/DESCRIPTION

Comment: have you tried a loop or an iteration over a list?

Comment: I haven’t and to be honest, I’m not too familiar with these (yet). Would you be so kind to share an example? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with {purrr}

```
library(Rspotify)
keys <- spotifyOAuth("rstats","***","***")


library(purrr)
# Create a vector of owners id 
owners_id <- c('11152045841', 'spotify', 'spotify')
# Create a vector of the corresponding playlist id
playlists_id <- c('0FJiPbIDGcxw6hx9dLVQPl', '37i9dQZF1DX5wiMM8SSK44', '37i9dQZF1DWT9SRKhOEUYj')

# Use purrr::map2 to retrieve a list of dataframe of the playlists
playlists <- map2(owners_id, playlists_id, ~ getPlaylistSongs(.x, .y, token = keys))

# You can also use purrr::map2_df if you want to bind if all in a unique data.frame
playlists <- map2_df(owners_id, playlists_id, ~ getPlaylistSongs(.x, .y, token = keys))
```

Comment: One other question, then I got everything covered! 

How would the above mentioned line look when you just need to use one list rather than both the username and ID to retrieve results? I tried using the example above and amended it to this function but it failed. 

``artist_info <- getArtistinfo("0X6CDvMiFMeLxVnKUq9oWy", token = keys)``

Getting the following error: ``Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default``

Thanks!